# Finding Process Name without using sudo in Linux

Tags: java, linux, process, sudo, pid

Here are the commands I am familiar with that do what you may think I want:
For the sake of this question; `"pn" = "process name"`

```
pgrep pn
sudo /sbin/service pn status
ps -fC pn
```

The problem I am running into is Java. `pgrep Java` will give me the PID of all java processes.  But if I know the exact name of a java application, let's call it coffee, `pgrep Coffee` gives me nothing.  However, `sudo /sbin/service Coffee status` will give me the exact PID of Coffee.  The problem is that I don't want and cannot use sudo in the script I am writing.  So how do I find Coffee's PID even though it's a Java app?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  There might be better answers but what I do is this

```
ps -efw | grep pn
```

Then I can use awk to get just the column I want so that its just the pid.

```
ps -efw | grep pn | awk '{print $2}'
```

EDIT:  Use the 'w' option in ps to get a wide output.  Sometimes the name does not show up without the 'w' there.

> w               Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
ps -ef| grep Coffee
```

Comment: The issue I seem to have with this is that the output contains all PIDs running in any folder named the same as Coffee /root/coffee/random.sh

Comment: you can use grep regex expression to better match or if it's only a case issue then with -i option

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the JPS (Java Process Status) tool.  I can't remember if it comes with the runtime environment or not.  It list out all currently running java processes, their PIDs, and the name of the Java application.  You can probably parse the output to get the values you're looking for.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html

Sample output:

```
jps
18027 Java2Demo.JAR
18032 jps
18005 jstat
```

Comment: I am getting Main for specific PIDs and not specific app name which when I do `sudo /sbin/service coffee status` it knows what that is